# building regex to get last section

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
service instance 2930 ethernet
description this is all character billing code not include tunnel id
encapsulation dot1q 2930
xconnect 1.1.1.2 333 encapsulation mpls
service instance 2931 ethernet 2931colin
description this is 2931 Billing Code for Colin
encapsulation dot1q 2931
xconnect 1.1.1.2 2931 encapsulation mpls
```

and would like to get only the LAST section where "service instance" starts...
e.g:

```
service instance 2931 ethernet 2931colin
description this is 2931 Billing Code for Colin
encapsulation dot1q 2931
xconnect 1.1.1.2 2931 encapsulation mpls
```

Can you please help me building the regex for that? I spent already 3 hours finiding an answer before posting it :(

Thanks

Comment: what language/tool are you using..regex implementation differs across languages/tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use greedy quantifier

```
(?s)service instance(?!.*service instance).*$
```

---

`(?s)` toggles the singleline mode which allows `.` to match newlines

`(?!.*service instance)` is a [zero width lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which would check for `service instance` and if it occurs,it wont match futher

`$` marks the end of string

So,this regex would match service instance only if theres no service instance ahead in the string allowing us to match the desired string

Comment: @user as i said it captures it in group 1..which language are you using

Comment: Doesn't group 2 captures the data since (?s) is a capturing group?

Comment: @raam86 (?s)  toggles the `singleline` mode option which allows `.` to match newlines